# Suddenly no data connection with S3 4.3 Jelly Bean

Tags: internet

Tonight my SGS3 suddenly stopped having data. Nothing has changed with regards to the APN. It just stopped.

My girlfriend who's on the same carrier has no problems although she has a postpaid subscription and I am using a prepaid sim. (Carrier still handles the same APN though). Just to be sure I have tried looking up her APN settings for comparison but discovered that the carrier is hiding those on the iPhone.

Other things I have tried:

- airplane mode on/off (many many times)
- apn settings from carrier for pre 2005 phones (gprs)
- reboot (many many times)
- soft reset
- factory reset

Nothing works... sms, calling everything is working but just no data connection.

Anyone has any ideas on what this could be and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to backup your data and perform a factory reset while keeping in mind to take out the micro sd card as it will be erased too.